# About Pro Tem moderator nominations... Is there a better way to discuss concerns with moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Under one user's nomination (michaelpri) are some valid comments that might better be answered by a conversation with the users themselves.

I don't know if this is done only for elected mods, but some sites create rooms where users can ask questions to their heart's content without leaving long comment threads under the nomination, and the nominee can provide more detailed answers.

Anyone can ask a question, and the other users can read all questions and answers and better evaluate the nominees.

Would this be a good idea here? I know I'm new enough to the community that I have not had interactions with all the moderators. I know we're not voting for the nominees, though, so perhaps it's not important?

Just a thought.

Comment: I *think* but I'm not sure, that that is only for elections. But, there is nothing preventing you from creating your own chat room and posting the link on meta. I'd welcome the chance to answer, I know that kenorb and I talked about some things which changed his voting some. I know personally I don't always come across well in comment exchanges.

Comment: I'm personally okay with a long comment thread under the candidate nomination, a la SE elections. But a chat room could work great too.

Answer (score 4):

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22853/pro-tem-mod-qa

I created a room for this. If you have questions you would like to ask of the mods, go ahead and ask them there. It would be nice if all moderator candidates could visit the room, so that the @ ping will work for your name.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about other sites, but on math, for mod elections, we have a thread where we compile questions for users who are running. The top X amount of questions (could 3,4,5, etc) are moved to an official thread where each candidate starts an answer that address all the questions. This way all answers per candidate are in one post. With chat, answers will be mixed up and not in any order making it hard to follow. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) post for what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've seen such questionnaires during elections (it might even be standard then). I've also seen rooms for less formal questions for *particular* candidates (and yes, they were more difficult to follow, and "@X" was always required.) It seems cleaner than what I see now on the pro tem meta question (I'm referring to the thread under michaelpri's nomination). Maybe, though, your idea can be implemented; I don't know much about how pro tems are chosen. I know it's not only by what the site participants think, but beyond that, it's a mystery.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I read the comments as well. For instance, one of the questions could be is what qualifications do you have that would make you an expert or quasi-expert in the field. [Here](http://definitions.uslegal.com/e/expert-witness/) is the US legal definition of experts. However, that definition would bar almost everyone under a certain age. I am just throwing ideas out there for whomever to consider.

Comment: Good point. Yes, that definition rules out even some doctors straight out of residency!